# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets"

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to run some code that has `import websocket`. However, I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket'
```

So from other questions/answers I found on here, in my cmd I ran `pip install websocket` and then also `pip install websocket-client` when the first one didn't run.

My Python code starts with these import statements:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import random
import time
import asyncio
import websockets
import threading
import os
from enum import Enum
from discord import Button, ButtonStyle
import requests
```

The error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\jvall\Downloads\psx-gambling-bot-mai2\psx-gambling-bot-main>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jvall\Downloads\psx-gambling-bot-mai2\psx-gambling-bot-main\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    import websockets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'

C:\Users\jvall\Downloads\psx-gambling-bot-mai2\psx-gambling-bot-main>
```

I tried `pip install websockets`, `pip3 install websockets`, `python -m pip install websocket-client`, and `pip install websocket-client`

Comment: Try 'pip install websocket_client' let's see how that goes

Comment: if that doesn't do. Let's try '. pip install websocket-server'

Answer (score 0):

What version of pip are you running?

```
pip --version
```

I just tried `pip install websockets` with pip 23.1.2 and it worked fine.

(answering because I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 0):

First off what OS are you using? What version of pip? I assume Linux or Mac because of your mention of pip3. But pip is for windows and pip3 for Linux.